# Inserting xml node values from reading a file in soap ui

Tags: xml, soap, groovy, soapui, soap-client

I have a requirement where there is an xml in my file system and I have to read tag values from that xml and populate in my soap request. I have totally no idea how do I do this.

I wrote a groovy script to read file:

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/Desktop/abc.txt")
fileContent = file.getText()
```

Now I want to read tag values from my source xml and populate in my soap request xml tags.

My sample xml is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <dto:dto>
         <mon:abc>
            <mon:HDR>
               <mon:MESSAGE_ID>abcd</mon:MESSAGE_ID>
               <mon:MSG_TIMESTAMP>2015-10-12T11:24:35-06:00</mon:MSG_TIMESTAMP>

            </mon:HDR>

         </mon:abc>
      </dto:dto>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have to read message_id from my sample xml into my soap request message id. Can someone guide how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the groovy script to extract the Message ID from the given file

Note that the sample you have provide does not have the proper data, missing namespaces.

```groovy
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
//change the file path here
def xml = new File('/absolute/file/path').text
def holder = new XmlHolder(xml)
def messageId = holder.getNodeValue('//*:MESSAGE_ID')
assert messageId, "Message Id is empty or null"
log.info "MessageId is : ${messageId}"
```

If you need the `messageId` to be used in other steps of the same test case, please store it in a *test case level property* using below additional statement:

`context.testCase.setPropertyValue('MESSAGE_ID', messageId)`

Later you can use in other steps (except groovy) as `${#TestCase#MESSAGE_ID}`

Use it in another groovy script of same test case as `context.expand('${#TestCase#MESSAGE_ID}')`